# Regular expression for validation purpose in JavaScript and/or node.js

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

In javascript and/or node.js, how to write a regular expression for the following purpose:

1) The text must contain at least one line and must not exceed 10000 lines.

2) Each line is made up of a string followed by an integer. The string alphabet is limited to "ACGTN", and its length must be at least 1 and at most 64. The integer must be within 0 to 9, i.e. length must be 1.

Here is an valid example:

```
ACCCGTTNNGTCCGGA3
ACCCGTTNNGTCCGGATTGAANNGT9
TTGGACCNAC0
```

Here is an invalid example: (contains out-of-alphabet character)

```
BACGGTA0
```

Another invalid example: (no integer at the second line)

```
ACGGTA0
TTGGACCNAC
```

Another invalid example: (string longer than 64 characters)

```
TTGGACCNACACCCGTTNNGTCCGGATTGAANNGTTTGGACCNACACCCGTTNNGTCCGGATTGAANNGTTTGGACCNACACCCGTTNNGTCCGGATTGAANNGT2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to validate all the file using a regular expression, use this one:

```
^([ACGTN]{1,64}\d\n){0,9999}[ACGTN]{1,64}\d$
```

Blender's answer is good too, but it is only for one line

Answer (score 2):

Regex, to the rescue:

```
^[ACGTN]{1,64}\d$
```

Just split the input up by the `\n` (newline character) and test each line against this regex.

Comment: Note that you need to surround this with the ^ and $ anchors to prevent sequences such as 0TTGGACCNAC0 and TTGGACCNAC00 from being considered valid.